# How to add multiple CSS files in the flask?

Tags: html, css, flask

I have two CSS files in my flask applications, `main.css` file, and `profile-pic.css` file. I want to apply `main.css` to every HTML file in the application and `profile-pic.css` to profile.html only. How can I achieve this in flask?

This is my flask structure:

```
flask
    static
        main.css
        profile-pic.css
    templetes
        profile-pic.html
        account.html
        ....
```

Comment: Are you using the template extension method? Like: `{% extends 'base.html' %}`?

Comment: yes, I'm using the template extension

Answer (score 1):

Read about using template inheritance (extension):

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/

You can put `main.css` in your base template.  In the extended, you can put `profile-pic.css`, like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block addl_css %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile-pic.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
....
....
```

Make sure you add the new block inside the `<HEAD>` section in `base.html`, so it can accept the new block:

```
{% block addl_css %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Ya I added the CSS file to my profile-pic.html like you said. But no effect in the browser

Comment: And you added `{% block addl_css %}{% endblock %}` to the `<HEAD>` section of `base.html`?